# Magento add custom refference to attributes and attributes sets

Tags: magento, attributes, adminhtml

I need to make individuals attributes sets and product attributes for users, and I was wondering is there a posibillity to add a custom refference to filter by on the product attributes and attributes sets?

Thank you

Comment: Where would you like to filter? In layered navigation? There no such filter 'by attribute set'. Filter by attributes? Magento allow that. I didn't understand anything in your question. What do you exactly need?

Comment: Sorry if it does not make sense, I want to load all the attributes sets that are present in Magento and then get from that collection only specific ones. For example I have 10 attributes sets, where 3 sets may be created by an admin with a specific role. I want to get for that admin only those 3 sets that he created. That is available for product attributes as well. Thank you.

Comment: Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->load()

Comment: Yes @zhartaunik, I agree, that is the way you load all the attributes sets, but I want a custom refference on them eg: custom_reff_id. Can I add on each entry in that collection somehow a new key ( like "custom_reff_id" ) ?

Comment: In my opinion you need to customize you magento. The easiest, but not clean, way is to add new column to this table and consist there your reference_id

Comment: Thank you, but I really dont want to make that because the database is EAV model. Thank you.